# Search in directory and subdirectories for missing files

Tags: python, search, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to search through a directory and associated subdirectories to see if these listed jpg files are missing. I have got it looping through one directory but cannot extend the search into any subdirectories.

I have tried using os.walk but it just loops through all files and repeats that all files are missing even if they are not. So I am not sure how to proceed.

This is the code that I have so far.

```
source = 'path_to_file'
paths = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Howdy']
for index, item in enumerate(paths):
      paths[index] = (source + '\\' + paths[index]+'.jpg')

mp = [path for path in paths if not isfile(path)]
for nl in mp:
      print(f'{nl}... is missing')
```

Comment: Please check if the file that you have created in your system is for example `Hello.jpg` not `hello.jpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage glob and the recursive parameter to do that in python :

```
import glob

source='./'
paths=['file1','file2','file3']
for path in paths:
        print(f"looking for {path} with {source+'**/'+path+'.jpg'}")
        print(glob.glob(source+"**/"+path+".jpg",recursive=True))
mp=[path for path in paths if not glob.glob(source+"**/"+path+".jpg",recursive=True)]
for nl in mp:
      print(f'{nl}... is missing')
```

(You can the remove the `for loop` line 5-7, it's just to clarify how glob works, the comprehension list itself is enough)

With the following folder :

```
.
├── file1.jpg
├── search.py
└── subfolder
    └── file3.jpg
```

It returns :

```
looking for file1 with ./**/file1.jpg
['./file1.jpg']
looking for file2 with ./**/file2.jpg
[]
looking for file3 with ./**/file3.jpg
['./subfolder/file3.jpg']
file2... is missing
```

Comment: Thank you L. Morin that is extremely helpful you have saved hours of my future work efforts this is just what I was after. I just needed to add os.chdir() and path+"*" so that I can just search for the text in the list and not the full path name.

Answer (score 1):

As you told that using `os.walk` you were unable to get your desired output, Here's a solution.

What i have done is using os `os.walk` i have searched the whole directory and then appended the file names to a list called `emty_list`. Then i have tried to check if the item in the list `file_name` is in `emty_list` or not.

```
import os
source = r'path'
emty_list=[]
file_name= ['hello.jpg', 'Hi.jpg', 'Howdy.jpg']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(f"{source}", topdown=False): #Listing Directory
    for name in files:
        emty_list.append(name)
for check in file_name:
    if check not in emty_list:
        print(f"File Not Found Error : File Name: {check}")
```

**Note: Please check if the file that you have created in your system is for example Hello.jpg not hello.jpg.**